# Does anyone have a datasheet for this Arira LCD?

Tags: lcd, datasheet

I emailed the manufacturer but they haven't responded to my email. I received this LCD screen in a grab bag from Jameco. Googled for a while and couldn't find anything related to the pinouts of this LCD screen. This is all I could gather.

Arira Design Inc

800-00013-20

REV 2

800-00013-20ASSY

94V0 AB20811E

WZ-6 E170968

Someone else on reddit was also looking for a datasheet for the device. He posted pictures of it as well. If anyone has the datasheet or knows how I can connect it to an Arduino I'd appreciate it.
These are his photos of it: https://i.stack.imgur.com/F0xW2.jpg

Comment: Did you know the part code for U1, U2, U5?

Comment: I'll check when I get home for U2 and U5. U1 are the last two lines I posted. 94V0 AB20811E  WZ-6 E170968 and I believe it was manufactured by motorola

Comment: Did you give a try to contact http://www.ariradesign.com ?

Comment: I sent them an email this past week but I haven't heard back from them yet

Comment: U2 says the following
ATMEL424
25010AN
6127

U5 says the following:
(can't make out the first line as someone used a black marker on it)
14A (hard to see the first character. might be a 3)
PREC

Comment: You happen to ever find the answer to this? I managed to track down the product on the Jameco site, but still no datasheet. But at least there's a manufacturer's part number: http://www.jameco.com/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/Product_10001_10001_2162898_-1

Comment: user38162: I haven't found a datasheet for it.  The manufacturer never emailed me back either :/

Answer (score 1):

It's an LCD for a fan controller.

I got one from Jameco as well, and desoldered the LCD. It had a fan speed display, etc.

The reason why there's no documentation on it is because it's probably a custom part. There's a segment of the display which says "1 800 SHAKLIFE" or something. Don't know why Jameco would sell this, though.

On the bright side, I got some SMD components, connectors, and a blue LED backlight module!

Side note: That thing on top is not some IR receiver. It's an LED. (Yes, also blue)

Comment: As @fuzzyhair2 said, it is part of a 5-Speed Fan Control Kit. I found this PDF which has more info about buttons and connectors:
http://datasheet.octopart.com/JE-FANKIT-Jameco-Reliapro-datasheet-8634092.pdf I found that info by googling "jameco 2100144"

Answer (score 0):

[image: Powered up the display].

The thing shows a fan speed value that can be changed up and down using the right most two buttons, but after a few seconds it starts flashing between 1 and F and the buttons stop responding and it shows "call 1-800-SHAKLEE". I am guessing that it senses there are no fan loads or something and assumes something went wrong. Other than scrap parts, it's practically useless, unless maybe for fan controlling? i did try to test the terminals on the back to see if they change Resistance, Voltage, PWM.. anything... but no luck maybe all loads have to be connected for it to function properly

Comment: This is really supplemental information for the question, not an answer, but because you're not the OP, I can't combine them. Since you included a nice picture, I can't turn it into a comment, either. So we'll let it stand as an "extended comment".

Answer (score 0):

https://www.studiored.com/client-work/consumer-product-design/shaklee/
I know, old thread and all that. Well thats what it is from, StudioRed/Shaklee Airsource air cleaner. Not that that helps any.

Comment: Thanks for adding some info, but in the future you should post this as a comment, since it doesn't answer the question.